# Excel column comparison using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel file in which there are some columns.

```
COL 1    | COL 2    | COL 3  

ABCD     |  ABC(D)  |   CDA  
AB CD    | ABC D    |   C D - (B)  
A B C D  | (ABCD)   |   ABCD  
ABC D    | ABDC     | ABC D  
A(BC ) D |  AD B - C|   AB CD
```

I want to compare every column with every other column and want to print similarities and differences  between columns.

for example :

1. comparing COL 1 and COL 2

   similarities :

   ```
   None
   ```

   differences :

   ```
   ABCD
   AB CD
   A B C D
   A(BC ) D
   ABC(D)
   ABC D
   (ABCD)
   ABDC
   AD B - C
   ```

then comparing COL 2 and COL 3 and then comparing COL 1 and COL 3.
Need only exact string match, even a whitespace considered as mismatch.
It may be possible that column number may increase and comparison starts from 2nd row of the column.

How can I implement such recursive comparison in Python which gives me fast processing output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xlrd`. First of all, read content from your file. Second, save three columns into three dictionaries, since dict works faster in comparison. Third, do comparison work and output the result.

I suggest you check API of xlrd and write code by yourself. Here is [link](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Any questions, feel free to ask.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

name = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
lname = {1:'g', 2:'b', 3:'v'}
common = {}
diff_name   = {}
diff_lname  = {}


for key in name.keys():
    if name[key] == lname[key]:
        common[key] = name[key]
    else:
        diff_name[key] = name[key]
        diff_lname[key] = lname[key]

print 'common part is:', common
print 'diff_name  is: ', diff_name
print 'diff_lname  is: ', diff_lname
```

Comment: how to compare dicts and get similar and dissimilar values?

Comment: @sam Use built-in functions of dictionary, such as has_key(), items(). Alternatively, you can store three columns into set. For instance, using set(a)-set(b) to find values in a but not in b.

Comment: @sam Any more question? If not, please confirm it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: yes last question. how I will compare 2 dicts. e.g. name = {1 : 'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'} and lname = {1 : 'g', 2:'a', 3:'v'}. How can I print common and difference between this 2 dicts? please give me example.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm might be

```
for colA in range(0, N):
     for colB in range (colA + 1, N - 1):
        compare(colA, colB)
```